# Python: Comparing two lists using a for-loop, how do I print the results correctly?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

```
import random

lst1 = []
lst2 = []
n = int(input('Step a: How many numbers in each list?  '))

for i in range(0, n):
    number1 = random.randint(1, 15)
    number2 = random.randint(1, 15)
    lst1.append(number1)
    lst2.append(number2)
    count = 0
    if lst1[i] > lst2[i]:
        count += 1
        print(f'{number1} : First List')
    else:
        print(f'{number2} : Second List')


print(f'Step b: First List{lst1}')
print(f'Step c: Second List{lst2}')
print('Step d:')
print('Larger number in each comparison:')
```

Program is supposed to make two lists and compare each element.

Current program prints like this:

```
Step a: How many numbers in each list?  5
12 : First List
14 : First List
14 : First List
15 : First List
5 : Second List
Step b: First List\[12, 14, 14, 15, 4\]
Step c: Second List\[5, 2, 8, 13, 5\]
Step d:
Larger number in each comparison:
```

I'm trying to get it to print like this:

```
Step a: How many numbers in each list?  5
Step b: First List\[12, 14, 14, 15, 4\]
Step c: Second List\[5, 2, 8, 13, 5\]
Step d:
Larger number in each comparison:
12 : First List
14 : First List
14 : First List
15 : First List
5 : Second List
```

Any suggestions?

I've tried to make functions out of them and kept getting errors. Very new to this and not sure what I should do.

Comment: Move the last 4 lines to before the `for` loop?

Comment: You are trying to do too much all at the same time. Instead, break this problem into pieces. First create the two lists. Then compare them. This means you should have two separate loops instead of just one loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a third list to store the comparison results and then printing the contents only at the end with another loop:

```
import random

lst1 = []
lst2 = []
comparison_results = []

n = int(input('Step a: How many numbers in each list? '))

for i in range(n):
    number1 = random.randint(1, 15)
    number2 = random.randint(1, 15)
    lst1.append(number1)
    lst2.append(number2)

    if lst1[i] > lst2[i]:
        comparison_results.append(f'{number1} : First List')
    elif lst1[i] < lst2[i]:
        comparison_results.append(f'{number2} : Second List')
    else:
        comparison_results.append(f'{number2} : In Both Lists')

print(f'Step b: First List {lst1}')
print(f'Step c: Second List {lst2}')
print('Step d: Larger number in each comparison:')
for result in comparison_results:
    print(result)
```

**Example Output:**

```
Step a: How many numbers in each list? 5
Step b: First List [5, 11, 9, 3, 4]
Step c: Second List [15, 11, 9, 13, 15]
Step d: Larger number in each comparison:
15 : Second List
11 : In Both Lists
9 : In Both Lists
13 : Second List
15 : Second List
```

Answer (score 3):

Construct the list first, then compare.

```
import random

lst1 = []
lst2 = []
n = int(input('Step a: How many numbers in each list?  '))

for i in range(0, n):
    number1 = random.randint(1, 15)
    number2 = random.randint(1, 15)
    lst1.append(number1)
    lst2.append(number2)

print(f'Step b: First List{lst1}')
print(f'Step c: Second List{lst2}')
print('Step d:')
print('Larger number in each comparison:')

for i in range(0, n):
    if lst1[i] > lst2[i]:
        print(f'{number1} : First List')
    else:
        print(f'{number2} : Second List')
```

Comment: This is a good answer, two loops makes a lot of sense for the structure the questioner wants. You might consider using `zip` too, to iterate over the values of the two lists directly, rather than via an index.